# Help finding a novel where a man goes through a wormhole to a futuristic religious dystopia

Tags: story-identification, religion

I read a novel about ten or fifteen years ago (which I didn't really enjoy very much) but it is now bothering me that I can't remember what it was.

At the start, this guys is on Earth and I think he is sent to a colony planet by some super rich super old dude via wormhole. When he gets to the colony he is waaay too far in the future and the whole place has broken down into a world governed by various religious orders.

The main character escapes into the desert at some point.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are lots of future religious dystopia, do you remember anything else? What kind of religions were there? Does the man return at the end? Is the man sent by force, by trickery, or does he go there willingly? Do you remember any other characters? Do you remember any general feeling about the society (e.g. everybody's crazy (pointing to Dick), women are better (pointing to Tepper), robots everywhere (pointing to Lem), …)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [The Empyrion Saga](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0745918727) by [Stephen R. Lawhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Lawhead) to me.

Comment: nice one. it's been bothering me for years and I didn't even enjoy it much!